# Is there a way to log output from creating a React Native project somewhere to use as reference?

Tags: react-native, redirect, visual-studio-code, console, io-redirection

I create React Native projects with `react-native init` and it outputs many lines in my console. Often there will be a bunch of warnings or errors that I want to work through one at a time, and would like to keep the logged output in a separate file.

**What I've Tried:**

I just copy-pasted the logged output into a file in VsCode. The problem is that it pastes as plain text by default, and doesn't have the informative colors that the console has (red for error, yellow for warning, etc).

**What I Want To Know:**

Is there a way I can format the text (ie. "Select Language Mode") in VsCode such that it have those informative colors? And is there a way I can automatically re-direct my console output to a file with this language mode preferences automatically set?